# Need help fixing "Failed to associate" error in Reaver

Tags: wifi, wpa

I am learning ethical hacking via an online course. During my practice, I am cracking the wifi password of my own router, but I am getting the following error:

```
WARNING: Failed to associate with XXXXXXXX (ESSID: XXX)
```

Can anyone guide me how I fix this issue? The device is in monitor mode and the command I am using is:

```
reaver -i wlan0mon -b XXXXXXX -vv
```

Answer (score 3):

After `-b` you should insert the mac address of your router. You may be able to find it if you run "`airodump-ng wlan0mon`"; make sure your device is in monitor mode. Airodump-ng comes with Kali, so if you're using Kali Linux you'll not have trouble using this command.

Remember, do not try this if you're not allowed to access the network you're trying to.